# Min width of facebook

Tags: css

I just want to know the minium width facebook has  today. How I can know it? I want to copy it for my webpage... just  that. Because I want to set my width in a tipical/best practice width now a days.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, do that, and nobody will visit your site.

Comment: do you any recommend min width?

Comment: You could look at the source code for Facebook's webpage... Right-click on the page and select "View Source" in 99% of browsers. But more to the point, why do you want to do this? Facebook has chosen a width that works for *their* design at the *current* moment. There's no guarantee that it will stay the same, and there's no guarantee that it's the *best* choice. You need to pick one that makes sense for your site, all things considered. Copying this is not going to make your site the same success that Facebook is.

Comment: I  did not talk about success.... I want to copy, so I dont have to think of a best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is their source:

```
.fbx #globalContainer {
    width: 981px;
}

#globalContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```